# Is torch.square(x) faster than torch.pow(x, 2)?

Tags: pytorch

I found several examples of code where `torch.pow(x, 2)` is used to square the components of a tensor. Would it be more performant to replace such instances with `torch.square(x)`?

I have not yet come up with a benchmark to test this; I was hoping someone with more knowledge of torch's internals would be able to expand on why one is faster than the other (or not).

Comment: why not test it yourself? also check x*x

Answer (score 0):

In my experiments using timeit for 1M tries to compute a square of a 4096 vector, I found:

1. `*` fastest with 8.55s
2. `square` with 12.51s
3. `pow` with 14.11s

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).